# Amount of VRAM in use?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, vram

When you go to the task manager, you can see how much RAM you're using.

Is there any way to find out how much VRAM you are using?

W7 64 bit here.
ATI Radeon HD 4890 card

**EDIT:**

GPU-Z and HWiNFO don't work.

ATI provides a tool too, but it keeps displaying 35MB in use. No matter what programs and games are open.

PerfStudio works, but is to advanced for everyday use, it is for analysing system recources while running a game. Has a built-in debugger and everything.

Comment: Would help with what GPU you are using, as there are a few floating around for a few chipsets.

Comment: Added it to my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, I found out that Process Explorer from SysInternals shows VRAM usage.

Answer (score 6):

Note: As it stands it appears this is only valid for Nvidia cards, GPU-Z does not appear to be able to get this information on Ati cards.

You can see how much video memory is in use on any reasonably new Nvidia graphics card using GPU-z, which you can get from http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/

For example my card shows:

[image]

Note the "Memory Used" field.  I believe this should be available on almost all current cards, though I don't have an Ati card to check.

Comment: No "Memory used" here.. Thanks anyways ;)

Comment: That's a bit of a pity, I'd hoped a similar kind of information was available on Ati cards.  I'll amend my answer to note that this currently only applies to Nvidia as it may be useful for the future if someone has a similar question, though for you specifically I will admit it is not much help.

Comment: It could be only my card is affected, or only the 4800 series. I'll look further myself too, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can use [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/) to determine the percentage of video RAM in use.  It shows up in the sensor readings as "GPU Memory Load" or "GPU Memory Utilization".</strike>  HWiNFO does not work as confirmed by the original question's author.

For **advanced users with *NVIDIA* cards**, you can also try the official [NVIDIA PerfKit](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit) software, which "gives you access to low-level performance counters inside the driver and hardware counters inside the GPU itself".

For **advanced users with *ATI* cards**, you can also try the official [GPU PerfStudio](http://developer.amd.com/tools/PerfStudio/Pages/default.aspx) software, which includes "a Frame Profiler that allows you to identify per draw call performance issues at the hardware counter level".  This *should* give you access to the VRAM usage, but alas, I am an NVIDIA user, so I cannot test this for you.

Comment: This one isn't working either..

Comment: @Simon Verbeke if you want to venture into the realm of the unknown, give GPU PerfStudio a shot (again, I can't vouch for it though - admittedly, I found it looking for a comparable program to the NVIDIA PerfKit).

Comment: Looks interesting :) Especially for the game I'm working on. Going to try and figure it out..

Comment: Hmm.. It requires me to attach it to an executable of a game. Not exactly what I'm looking for. But seems a useful program, thanks!

Comment: @Simon Verbeke no problem, sorry it wasn't what you were looking for.  I'll try to keep an eye out for any program that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Download Process Explorer from this url:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Then drag procecexp application to your desktop. Double click to run it and search for Nvidia in my case and kill the tree.  Worked like a charm. Stable Diffusion in my case and the out of memory warning is cleared.